# Error when importing vue-cli app in another repo

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I created a component library using vue-cli 3, and then pulled that into another repo to use the components. Now I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "@vue/app" relative to directory "/{path_to_project}/node_modules/{vue_cli_app}"
    at {path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249)
    at OptionManager.init ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368)
    at File.initOptions ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212)
    at new File ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135)
    at Pipeline.transform ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46)
    at transpile ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50)
    at Object.module.exports ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:175)
    at {path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249)
    at OptionManager.init ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368)
    at File.initOptions ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212)
    at new File ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135)
    at Pipeline.transform ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46)
    at transpile ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50)
    at Object.module.exports ({path_to_project}/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:175)
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (aggregation.bundle.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ec9b411d2dc4def5406f:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (select.vue:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ec9b411d2dc4def5406f:54)
    at Object.Array.concat.path (vue-multi-select.component.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ec9b411d2dc4def5406f:54)
    at Object.Array.concat._extends (app-files.generated.js:86)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ec9b411d2dc4def5406f:54)
    at Object.Array.concat.module.exports (app.js:111)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ec9b411d2dc4def5406f:54)
```

This is coming from the autogenerated `.babelrc` in the vue-cli project:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@vue/app",
    "vue"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to change the `.babelrc` reference so that it can be used when imported elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the correct way to do this would be to reference the .babelrc from the project importing the library.  My solution would be:

1. Transpile the library **prior** to exporting
2. Build into a dist directory
3. Import the built dist directory into the project which is using the library.

I believe babel can do something simple like `babel -d ./dist` to build the directory, you can see the documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)